# Vscode Git commit history shows upper folder's change

Tags: flutter, github, visual-studio-code

[image]

I created flutter new project in path `/Users/hayat/flutter_development/flutter_project/flutter_application_1`.

But VScode shows **10k changes** in commit source control.

when I see those changes, it shows all changes in `/Users/hayat/`, which is upper folder than pwd.

I don't know why it happens and how to make it show only changes of `flutter_application_1`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your probably made a `git init` or at least have a `.git` folder in your `/Users/hayat/` folder.

Best thing you can do is to delete the `.git` folder in `/Users/hayat/`, then you will be able to commit normal changes in your project folder. If VSCode don't detect any git repository, then, use the `git init` command to link your application folder to your remote git repository.